# Human face attractiveness estimation

Tags: neural-network, multiclass-classification, object-recognition

Needed for dating portal. I currently use  [OpenFace](https://cmusatyalab.github.io/openface/) to extract features with DNN. (I don't know whether they have a usable meaning) Then compare them to some model faces' features using euclidian distance and rate according to these values. Result is below satisfactory. I'm thinking about SVM, but I need to distinguish between a few levels (rank 1-5). OneVsAll? Not sure if I need 5 classifiers just to get the measure of similarity. Any ideas.

What have been tried:

1. Extracted features for a set of model faces (photos chosen by me from google); extracted features from a test set and sort photos according to average (or minimum) euclidian distance to these model features; Visual estimation: many from those which are in top 10's are noticeably not similar (and not attractive) compared to a model set
2. Labeled test set (according to my taste) as 1 and 0 classes (70 and 1640 samples) and CV set (14 and 194). Extracted features, trained RBF SVM, performed parameter search.

Comment: Beauty admits gradation; I'd use a regression model and loss. Do you have Likert scale training data?

Comment: I have to use photos only. Do you mean to train regression (using differences with models as features) using natural values (marks) as labels? Also not sure, do you mean something special by "and loss"? Sorry I'm new to the field.

Comment: Examples of regression losses are the MSE and MAE. You mention results; can you edit your post to tell us more about what you tried and what the results were? Welcome to the site! I think face recognition features should work, since they are used to distinguish people, and you want to broadly distinguish beautiful people from the rest. One question on my mind is that since beauty is in the eye of the beholder, you should perhaps try to pair people with those _they_ would find attractive. Use a recommender system rather than find the most beautiful users. Have you thought about this?

Comment: Updated the answer . The customer doesn't want a recommender system. Inferring recommendations from each person's likes is an option, but do you think the small number of positive examples might be a problem ? (We can't ask user to make thousands of likes for the system to start working)

Comment: Face recognition features from OpenFace are biometric measurements designed to be robust against changes that may affect your attractiveness ratings, including subjective attractiveness from a photo due to lighting, make-up, pose/expression. Skin blemishes and other imperfections are likely to be ignored by OpenFace's algorithms, since they are not suitable for generic biometrics and might be temporary. Similarly hairstyle and grooming are likely ignored.

Comment: Neil, have you seen any docs regarding which traits it extracts/ignores?

Comment: No I don't have specific docs, but have seen OpenFace used as identity classifier. It is the fact that it works well for identity which makes me skeptical of its ability to represent attractiveness.